# Select2: How to add extra information for selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

By default [select2](https://select2.github.io/) uses a dict with the keys `id` and `text`.

My server part returns additional data, which I would like to process on the client in JavaScript.

This seems to be a common question:

https://select2.github.io/options.html#does-select2-include-extra-information-in-these-events

But unfortunately there are no docs for it up to now.

I registered to the "select2:select" event, and can handle it, but how to get to the extra mydata which I get?

Example result of the server side:

```
{
 'id': '1',
 'text': 'First Item',
 'mydata': 'foo'
}
```

How can I reach "foo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it: `evt.params.data.mydata`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mywidget').on('select2:select', function(evt){
        alert(evt.params.data.mydata);
    });
})
```